# Framework folder getting generated inside dynamic framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, archive

I am creating a dynamic framework using Swift. When I build the framework, the resulting artifact has a `Framework` folder that has a bunch of system dylibs that I don't expect.
I am using this documentation for reference - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002253-99920-BAJFEJFI

Because of this folder and libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib, the app's release archive is getting rejected by iTunes upload.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found out the solution to this. In my framework build settings, I had `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` enabled which should have been disabled. Not sure why it was enabled in the first place, since I didn't write the framework, someone else did. But I think it might have been because they started the project using an iOS app template instead of the framework template.